# LSTM NN for timeseries modelling: Error: Inputs to a layer should be tensors

Tags: r, deep-learning, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to set up a univariate LSTM neural network to forecast a timeseries and I'm getting stuck at the same error message over and over again. When I define the LSTM model it returns: Error: TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got '<keras.src.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7fe7fdec8820>' (of type <class 'keras.src.engine.sequential.Sequential'>) as input for layer 'lstm_4'.
Even thought the input data is, according to my knowledge, in the correct format. Any help is much appreciated.

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)

# Split the data into training and test sets
train_data <- data[1:4, ]
test_data <- data[2:nrow(data), ]

# Normalize the data
normalize <- function(x) {
  (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)
}
train_data$value <- normalize(train_data$value)
test_data$value <- normalize(test_data$value)

# Prepare the training data
lag <- 3  # Number of lag observations

train_y <- train_data$value[(lag + 1):nrow(train_data)]

# Create an empty matrix for train_x with appropriate dimensions
train_x <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(train_data) - lag, ncol = lag)

# Assign values to train_x
for (i in 1:(nrow(train_data) - lag)) {
  train_x[i, ] <- as.numeric(train_data[i:(i + lag - 1), 1])
}


# Reshape train_x to 3D tensor
train_x <- array(train_x, dim = c(dim(train_x)[1], dim(train_x)[2], 1))

# Define the LSTM model
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 50, input_shape = c(dim(train_x)[2], 1)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)
```

I tried different ways to format the training data using array and matrix but both options returned the same error.

Any help is much appreciated

**Edit**
Here is some of the data I'm using:

```
 data = read.table(
  text =  'year value
          1990  30614250
          1991  30761180
          1992  30678770
          1993  30819730
          1994  31105680
          1995  31890420',
  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: sounds like you are having a data formatting issue, try to find a way to share an example slice of your real `data` (either as a publicly available file or paste-dump) and how you read it into `r` so other folks can reproduce (and help with) the specific error you are hitting

Comment: @Nate Added some pieces of data! Thanks :)

Comment: updated to show a better way to and do it like that with something like `read.table()`, I'm guessing that still might not be enough because the column types might not be right.  But now anyone with a `r` session can copy and pasete that block and get an object `data`. The thing with code examples is all of the read-in functions matter, because they have different behaviors. Also you probably have to update that `data[1:25,]` subset call now

Comment: updated the data references!

Comment: what library does `keras_model_sequential()` comes from, like edit to be `{{library}}::keras_model_sequential()`, and follow that pattern for other imported funcs

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Suggested edits have been made